# Azure not publishing Node.js App correctly

Tags: node.js, azure, cloud, project, publish

#### TL;DR

- Node.js app hosted on Azure as a Cloud Service.
- Publishing fails(app not uploaded) but appears to have worked.

#### Explained:

I have an account on Windows Azure where I have used both Websites and Cloud Services.  I moved my website to a cloud service to be able to use custom domains.

Since moving, I use Azure cmdlets to publish my Node.js webserver. Before publishing worked fine, usually taking between 5 and 10 minutes to complete. Once published, the website contains the most recent content.

My problem is that now, publishing takes less than 2 minutes, no errors are thrown, and the content is not updated. **Why is my app not publishing it's content?**

Below is my publishing output:

```
PS C:\Projects\Azure\CloudServices\jwbsite\JWB> ls

    Directory: C:\Projects\Azure\CloudServices\jwbsite\JWB

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----          9/8/2012  10:22 AM            bin
d----         9/12/2012   3:30 PM            controllers
d----         9/11/2012   1:16 PM            data
d----         9/12/2012   4:00 PM            extensions
d----         9/10/2012   2:37 PM            models
d----         9/12/2012   2:45 PM            node_modules
d----         9/12/2012   3:23 PM            public
d----          9/8/2012  10:28 AM            views
-a---         9/25/2012   3:44 PM        411 package.json
-a---         9/13/2012  11:14 AM        224 robots.txt
-a---         9/17/2012   2:45 PM        605 routes.js
-a---         9/17/2012  10:59 AM       1902 server.js
-a---         8/25/2012   1:28 PM       3251 Web.cloud.config
-a---         8/25/2012   1:28 PM       3251 Web.config

PS C:\Projects\Azure\CloudServices\jwbsite\JWB> Publish-AzureServiceProject

Publishing  to Windows Azure. This may take several minutes...

4:27:17 PM - Preparing runtime deployment for service 'jwbsite'
4:27:20 PM - Preparing deployment for jwbsite with Subscription ID: ABCDEFGH-IJKL-MNOP-QRST-UVWXYZ012345...
4:27:21 PM - Connecting...
4:27:27 PM - Verifying storage account 'jwbsite'...
4:27:27 PM - Uploading Package...
4:27:39 PM - Upgrading...
4:27:50 PM - Created Deployment ID: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE.
4:27:50 PM - Starting...
4:27:50 PM - Initializing...
4:27:51 PM - Instance JWB_IN_0 of role JWB is ready.
4:27:51 PM - Instance JWB_IN_1 of role JWB is ready.
4:27:51 PM - Instance JWB_IN_2 of role JWB is ready.
4:27:51 PM - Instance JWB_IN_3 of role JWB is ready.
4:27:52 PM - Created Website URL: http://jwbsite.cloudapp.net.
4:27:52 PM - Complete.

PS C:\Projects\Azure\CloudServices\jwbsite\JWB>
```

Let me know, I appreciate the help.

Comment: this won't answer the question, but if you delete the deployment does the problem recur?

Comment: @JimO'Neil When you say deployment, which files are you talking about?

Comment: When you redeploy you are updating the existing service in place; I am wondering if creating a NEW service will "clear" the problem or perhaps shed more light.  Look at the Remove-Azuredeployment and Remove-AzureService cmdlets.  Again, doesn't "fix" it but may work around it and/or give more information as to why it's not working

Comment: I've been working with Azure's technical support and they have no idea why it's not working, but they said they will upload what I have for me. I'll post back here if I ever figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else is having this problem or Google is sending your here, I did find the cause of the error.

### CHECK YOUR FILENAME/PATH LENGTHS!

If the filenames are too long then the package will not be uploaded to Azure. I found this out by trying to publish to the emulation of Azure, which gave me the correct errors.  I'm not sure why it doesn't give the errors when pushing to the real Azure instance.

> **Node.js Note:**
>
> The main source for filenames/paths that are too long are the modules.
>   When installing modules through NPM, the module will install it's
>   dependencies that aren't present at the time. Be sure to look through
>   your module file structure and try to slim it down(I'm working on a
>   script to balance it for you).

The Azure support team were extremely helpful in trying to get to the bottom of this confusing problem, they worked with me for almost 2 months to get my site back up and running.

If you are having the same or similar issue, try deploying to the local emulation of Azure and see what errors you get back.

I feel stupid for getting this error, but hopefully my stupid can help avoid someone else's.

Comment: I'm new to Node: can I modify the modules folder names manually to make them shorter? Will it somehow badly affect the application? I mean: can I do it without causing errors?

Comment: "I'm working on a script to balance it for you". Did you finish it? ;)

Comment: @Ludwik11 I think that was a quote from a Github comment or something, I don't have a script right now, and there might already be some other things out there. As far as renaming the folders, you don't want to do that. The most important thing to do is limit your project location (don't start with a long path) and move as many modules to the root as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I use this module to make my paths shorter
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatten-packages
It fixed the problem